# how a group of programmer work together on a server?

Tags: asp.net, .net

I am a student and I'm currently doing senior project. I'm required to work on the application control or application platform to let a group of programmer work together on a server with the security. I would like to know how a group of programmer work together on a server and how to work using visual studio 2010 on a server.
Thanks

Comment: Do you mean how do many programmers work on one asp.net project, or do you mean how do you control many users logging into a single server?

Comment: I mean how do many programmers work on one asp.net project on a single server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll probably want to create user accounts for each programmer on the server and allow them `ssh` access. Look into [git](http://git-scm.com/) for project version control.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have to use a version control system for your code such as SVN, which is one of the most popular.
There are also some other popular systems like GIT. You should try them both and see what fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

i recommed your download [here !](http://www.softec.lu/site/ClrProjects/SubversionSharp)